# Group WooCommerce downloads by product in a dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, grouping, product

I sell online courses in my website using WooCommerce. Each course(product) has number of downloadable files.
Unfortunately, WooCommerce does not group each product downloads together and make a long list of available downloads. If someone buy several courses, there will be a very long and confusing list of downloads which is not user-friendly.

I am looking for some codes (PHP, Java, CSS) to group each product downloads together under a drop-down menu. This way if someone buy 7 courses, then in download page there will be seven dropdown lists and by clicking on each one, downloads of that specific product just appear.

I used below PHP code. It groups downloads together but there is no drop-down menu.

```
/**
 * Group Downloadable products by product ID
 *
 * @param array $downloads
 * @return array
 */
function prefix_group_downloadable_products( array $downloads ) {
    $unique_downloads = [];

    foreach ( $downloads as $download ) {
        $list = [
            'download_url' => $download['download_url'],
            'file_name'    => $download['file']['name']
        ];

        if ( array_key_exists( $download['product_id'], $unique_downloads ) ) {
            $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ]['list'][] = $list;
            continue;
        }

        $data = $download;
        $data['list'] = [ $list ];
        $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ] = $data;
    }

    return $unique_downloads;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 
'prefix_group_downloadable_products' );


/**
 * Show number list of downloadable files for group product
 * 
 * @param array $download
 * @return void
 */ 
function prefix_downloads_column_download_file( array $download ) {
    $lists = $download['list'];

    if ( empty( $lists ) ) {
        _e( 'No Download Files', 'storefront' );
        return;
    }

    echo '<ol>';

    foreach ( $lists as $list ) {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $list['download_url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file">';
        echo esc_html( $list['file_name'] );
        echo '</a></li>';
    }

    echo '</ol>';
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-file', 'prefix_downloads_column_download_file' );
```

Also, this code causes an error appears in "my orders" and "order report" page, preventing to display downloads there. The error is this:

> Warning: Undefined array key "list" in /home/beatop/domains/sdrecords.ir/public_html/wp-content/themes/hello-theme-child-master/functions.php on line 156
> No Download Files

The line 156 is related to this: `$lists = $download['list'];`

How to rectify this error and add drop-down menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check first that `$download['list']` exist, to avoid that issue.

To get a dropdown of downloads grouped by product, some changes and additions are needed *(JavaScript/jQuery is required)*.

**Note *(update)*:** On **email notifications**, we keep the Downloads table as it is by default, as the dropdown can't work.

The following code will handle this dropdown **everywhere, in the front end**:

```php
// Group downloads data by product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'prefix_group_downloadable_products', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_downloadable_items', 'prefix_group_downloadable_products', 10, 2 );
function prefix_group_downloadable_products( $downloads = array(), $order = null ) {
    // Only on front-end
    if ( is_admin() || ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) { 
        return $downloads;
    }

    $unique_downloads = []; // Initializing

    foreach ( $downloads as $download ) {
        $list = [
            'download_url' => $download['download_url'],
            'file_name'    => $download['file']['name']
        ];

        if ( array_key_exists( $download['product_id'], $unique_downloads ) ) {
            $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ]['list'][] = $list;
            continue;
        }

        $data = $download;
        $data['list'] = [ $list ];
        $unique_downloads[ $download['product_id'] ] = $data;
    }
    return $unique_downloads;
}

// Display a dropdown of the downloads by product
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-file', 'customize_downloads_columns' );
function customize_downloads_columns( $download = array() ) {
    $lists = isset($download['list']) ? $download['list'] : array();

    if ( empty( $lists ) ) {
        _e( 'No Download Files', 'storefront' );
        return;
    }

    echo '<select class="downloads-dropdown">
    <option value="">'. __(' Select download', 'storefront' ) .'</option>';

    foreach ( $lists as $list ) {
        printf( '<option value="%s">%s</option>', 
        esc_url($list['download_url']), esc_html($list['file_name']) );

    }
    echo '</select>';
}

// Javascript: Trigger the download when selecting a file in the dropdown
add_action( 'wp_head', 'trigger_download_from_selected_file_js' );
function trigger_download_from_selected_file_js() {
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('downloads') || is_wc_endpoint_url('view-order') || is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
        wc_enqueue_js("$(document.body).on('change', 'select.downloads-dropdown', function(){
        if( $(this).val() != '' ) {
            window.location.href = $(this).val();
        }
        });");
    }
}
```

You will get something like *(in My account > Downloads page)*:

[image]

In My account > View Order and in Order received *(thankyou)* pages:

[image]

The downloads table on email notifications stays unchanged *(default WooCommerce behavior)*:

[image]

---

**Addition for email notifications (optional)**

Replace the downloads table, with a text linked to My Account "downloads" section:

```php
// Remove the downloads table
add_action( 'woocommerce_init', function(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( WC()->mailer(), 'order_downloads' ), 10 );
});

// Email notifications: Display a text linked to My Account downloads
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'display_linked_text_to_my_account_downloads', 9, 4 );
function display_linked_text_to_my_account_downloads( $order, $sent_to_admin = false, $plain_text = false, $email = '' ) {
    $show_downloads = $order->has_downloadable_item() && $order->is_download_permitted() && ! $sent_to_admin && ! is_a( $email, 'WC_Email_Customer_Refunded_Order' );
    
    if ( ! $show_downloads ) {
        return;
    }

    $text_align    = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
    $downloads_url = wc_get_endpoint_url('downloads', '', get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) );
    ?>
    <h2 class="woocommerce-order-downloads__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
    <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 40px;" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;">
                <?php printf( __('Downloads are available in your Account %s.', 'storefront'),
                '<a href="' . $downloads_url . '" class="button">'. __('"Downloads" section', 'storefront') .'</a>'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php 
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated my code answer: The email notifications are unchanged, so the default Downloads table with download links is displayed (not grouped by product). So now the code doesn't have any impact on email notifications. Optionally, if you want, you can replace the downloads table, with a text linked to My Account "downloads" section (see the addition)...